# wpbakery elements shortcode implement in php

Tags: php, wordpress, wpbakery

I have created a shortcode through wpbakery Add Element section. I am trying to apply this shortcode in PHP

> Here is the shortcode

```
[vc_masonry_grid post_type="post" max_items="10" grid_id="vc_gid:1592135090064-3fb6b6dd-7144-2" taxonomies="16"]
```

> Here is shortcode with PHP code which I have applied in PHP file but it's showing nothing.
>
> I got this function from here 
>   https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

```
echo do_shortcode( '[vc_masonry_grid post_type="post" max_items="10" grid_id="vc_gid:1591334217992-a1326795-3e97-8" taxonomies="16"]' );
```